# python dynamic super class change

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to define super class by the situation like followings.

```
class A:
  pass

class B:
  pass

class Z(object):
  pass

if condition == a:
   z  = Z(A)
elif condition == b:
   z = Z(B)
```

Is it possible in python?

Comment: Your design is probably broken if you rely on a class changing it's super-class dynamically. Likely, you require some form of composition rather than inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found the way to do this.

```
class A:
  pass

class B:
  pass

def createZ(sup):
  class Z(sup):
    def __init__(self):
      pass
  return Z

z_a = createZ(A)()
z_b = createZ(B)()
```